# c # Unable to highlight text box using mouse when display form in panel of splitcontainer

Tags: c#

I have a form1 with a splitcontainer. I have put a button on the left panel, whenever user click the button, form2 will be displayed in the right panel.

The question now is, i am not allowed to highlight the textbox in form2 with mouse. But i still can use the keyboard to highlight.

Comment: What __is__ the question??

Comment: I can't use my mouse to move the cursor inside the TextBox's text at all

Comment: How would that help? That is just what he does __not__ want..

Comment: Sorry , it doesn't help me . i still have problem with cursor mouse  in textbox when i add a form in splitcontainer .

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).